# Strange behavior of performing mouseover over a textarea in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, textarea, prototypejs, mouseover

I have a strange problem I can't wrap my head against.  It is present only in Chrome.  The library I'm using is Prototype 1.6.

Basically, I have two elements wrapped into a container element.  First of the two children elements is visible, the second one is hidden.  Inside the hidden element I have a textarea element.  When I mousover the container element, the first child should hide, second one should show itself.  When I mouseout, the behavior should be opposite.  You can see it here, along with the bug :)

http://jsfiddle.net/gmM9m/2

For some reason, in Chrome when I mouseover the textarea, the elements start blinking because they constantly turn themselves on and off.  Does anyone have any idea what causes this behavior and how can I circumvent it?

Thank you!
Luka

Comment: Chrome appears to fire onmouseout whenever moving over the textarea, so it seems as if it's not propagating correctly. I'm seeing if I can find a way that doesn't feel hackish.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've gotten is adding the event to the callback function for the mouseout and making sure that it's coming from the element you want. It seems kind of hackish, but perhaps it's a bug in Chrome. I'm seeing it as well, but wong2 does not seem to be seeing it.

See my revision, still a slight stutter on initial mouseover.

http://jsfiddle.net/gmM9m/10/

Comment: Thank you.  It's a lot closer then I got, but I'll probably have to try and figure out a different way to layout my page because of that initial stutter.  Hopefully the fix comes out soon.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.(I'm not familar with JQuery's `observe` method, so I use JavaScript's `addEventListener` instead)

```
$('container').addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
    $('front').hide();
    $('back').show();
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);

$('container').addEventListener("mouseout", function(event){
    $('front').show();
    $('back').hide();
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

The point is `stopPropagation`. Run it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RDXzR/

Comment: I still get the same behavior.  Try and move the mouse over textarea and you'll see what I mean.  Once again, it's only Chrome-specific.

Comment: @Lukich I know what you mean and this really works for me. I tested it wit h Chrome dev 12.0.725 on Windows7

Comment: Alright, I checked Windows and Mac builds of 10.0.648.205 Chrome, and it's happening on both for me, so possibly the problem is being fixed in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

I just run into similar problem and solved it with using jquery "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" event
see http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, we're still using Prototype at work :(